# The name does not exist. Setting variables inside if

Tags: c#

I'm beginner at C# and I'm making a simple application. But I still don't understand how could I return this array called "newsy" from this function. I can't set this variable inside an array. I've got this error:

The name 'newsy' does not exist in the current context.

Please help me.

```
private string[] get_news(string URL)
    {
        XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(URL);
        while (textReader.Read())
        {

            if (textReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (textReader.Name == "news") {
                    string News = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    string[] newsy = { News };
                }
                if (textReader.Name == "link")
                {
                    string Link = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    string[] newsy = { Link };
                }
            }
        }
        return newsy;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to learn about [scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132.aspx) - in particular block scope.

`newsy` is declared in an inner scope to the `return` statement, where it is not available.

Declare it in the outer scope and you will be fine:

```
private string[] get_news(string URL)
{
    XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(URL);
    string[] newsy = null;
    while (textReader.Read())
    {
        if (textReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (textReader.Name == "news") {
                string News = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                newsy = new string[] { News };
            }
            if (textReader.Name == "link")
            {
                string Link = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                newsy = new string[] { Link };
            }
        }
    }
    return newsy;
}
```

Note how `newsy` is declared (but not assigned to) outside the `while` block. Also see how inside the `while`, there are assignments to `newsy`, but no new declaration (which would not be legal).

It is worth noting that if `Name` is neither one of `"news"` or `"link"`, `newsy` will be `null` - it may or may not be what you want - you can always assign an empty string array during declaration:

```
string[] newsy = new string[] {};
```

Comment: Ehh, every time I remove string[] before Newsy I get 12 errors. That I ; is expected here: "{ Link };" and same on { News } I tried also copy-pasting your code but It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Daniel - did you notice the `string[] newsy;` just after the declaration of the `XmlTextReader`? I have updated the answer so it will compiler without error.

Comment: Your update code works! I think I know now what was my error. Thanks for great response. I used this site for my PHP problems, but C# is slightly different. Thanks once again. : )

Answer (score 2):

You need to create newsy outside of the `if` blocks (just once).

The important concept here is the "scope" of a variable.  When you declare a variable in C#, it only exists between the *innermost* set of `{`...`}` containing the declaration.

So in your code, if the name is `"news"`, you create a new string variable called `newsy` - but that variable lives inside the set of `{`...`}` after the `if`, and is gone once the program exits them.  If the name is `"link"`, you create a (different!) new string variable called `newsy`, but that also goes away at the end of that `if`.  Either way, by the time you get to the `return` statement, there's still no `newsy` anymore.

So you need to declare `newsy` at the same level as the `return` statement - inside the braces around the function body, but not inside the ones around the `while` body or any of the `if`s:

```
    XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(URL);
    string[] newsy;
    while (textReader.Read())
    {
```

...

Now, you also have to change the assignment, because if you do `string[] newsy` inside one of those inner blocks, you will still create a new variable that only exists inside that block and hides the outer one.  So instead of declaring it (with `string[]`), just assign to the existing one, with no type declaration:

```
            if (textReader.Name == "news") {
                string News = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                newsy = { News };
            }
```

And that should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `newsy` outside of the `while` loop:

```
private string[] get_news(string URL)
    {
        string [] newsy;
        XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(URL);
        while (textReader.Read())
        {

            if (textReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (textReader.Name == "news") {
                    string News = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    newsy = { News };
                }
                if (textReader.Name == "link")
                {
                    string Link = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    newsy = { Link };
                }
            }
        }
        return newsy;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
private string[] get_news(string URL)
        {
            XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(URL);
            string[] newsy=null;
            while (textReader.Read())
            {

                if (textReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (textReader.Name == "news") {
                        string News = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                         newsy = { News };
                    }
                    if (textReader.Name == "link")
                    {
                        string Link = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                         newsy = { Link };
                    }
                }
            }
            return newsy;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable inside a block (even an if block), it remains scoped at that level:

```
if (textReader.Name == "news") {
    string News = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
    string[] newsy = { News };
}

// newsy no longer exists
```

In order to return newsy you either need to declare at an outer scope or return it immediately.

```
    XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(URL);
    string[] newsy;

    while (textReader.Read())
    {

        if (textReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (textReader.Name == "news") {
                string News = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                newsy = { News };
            }
            if (textReader.Name == "link")
            {
                string Link = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                newsy = { Link };
            }
        }
    }
    return newsy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `string[] newsy;` before the while statement, and then just use newsy like this:
`newsy = {Link}`, that will fix your problem.